# Issue when building a Kubernetes Docker container for Spark using the Dockerfile provided with Spark source

Tags: apache-spark, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Kubernetes container for Spark, using the instructions provided in the Spark source code. I am using the Docker file provided here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile

However, the paths specified the Dockerfile does not match the folder structure of the Spark source code. For example,

1. There is no 'jar' directory in the source code. But the docker file does a 'COPY jars /opt/spark/jars'
2. The entrypoint.sh is located in 'resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh' but the Docker file tries to copy it from 
   "COPY ${img_path}/spark/entrypoint.sh /opt/" where "ARG img_path=kubernetes/dockerfiles"
3. Similarly "COPY ${k8s_tests} /opt/spark/tests" also seems to have incorrect source directory.

What am i missing?

Comment: Why not pull the image from https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/spark/ instead of building it yourself?

Comment: I removed the `kubernetes` tag since I don't actually see anything relevant to Kubernetes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question of "What am I missing?" would be that they are not using the a plain `docker build -t <tag> .` from that directory. Instead, they have a build script at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6c2d351f5466d42c4d227f5627bd3709c266b5ce/bin/docker-image-tool.sh which, among other things, checks to see if the jars are built first per https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6c2d351f5466d42c4d227f5627bd3709c266b5ce/bin/docker-image-tool.sh#L155-L157

In addition to that, it actually creates a folder structure and copies scripts and dependent files in place at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6c2d351f5466d42c4d227f5627bd3709c266b5ce/bin/docker-image-tool.sh#L89-L127 which is why you also see failures for missing `entrypoint.sh` and other arguments.

Edit:

I previously added something about using the official image mentioned by @cookiemonster but then I noticed it isn't actually an official image. I couldn't find any published official image by Apache so I removed that comment. You could definitely use a built image by someone else. But you can make that decision as I don't want to recommend any random images that I cannot vet myself if they are not supported upstream.

Comment: Yes ! That is exactly right. Here are more details:

I downloaded the source code and tried to run `docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .` It is not meant to be done like that. You first have to run _./make-distribution_ with _-PKubernetes_. This gives you the Spark distribution as a .tgz. When you unzip it, you will see the directory structure as expected by the Dockerfile

Comment: @buckeye13 Were you able to build the image?